# Required Help in RDP Automation

Tags: powershell, rdp

Below script is to Automate RDP and I am stuck with below two points:

> How to map local drive as mapped drive in RDP session(tsclient) using
> powershell script/command

> Example like this in RDP :  drivestoredirect:s:value

**RDP Automation - PowerShell Script :**

```html
cmdkey /list | ForEach-Object{if($_ -like "*target=TERMSRV/*"){cmdkey /del:($_ -replace " ","" -replace "Target:","")}}
echo "Connecting to Server Name"
$Server="Server Name"
$User="Username"
$Password="Password"
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$Server /user:$User /pass:$Password
mstsc /v:$Server
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client" /v "AuthenticationLevelOverride" /t "REG_DWORD" /d 0 /f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control all aspects of your connection when using mstsc.exe via command line. The information for mapping local resources in the TS session are stored in the RDP file.

If not specified, it will use the default.rdp file located in "My Documents" folder (hidden file).

If you configure the default RDP to map local resources, all subsequent connections will also have the local resources mapped... but if you change it again, it will apply to all next connections.

So a better approach will be to create one *.rdp file and use it as a template in your script:

**Create Template RDP file:**

- Launch mstsc.exe
- Configure all options as per your needs
- Save the file somewhere and use it in your script (i.e C:\Temp\MyRDPtemplate.rdp)

[image: add local resources]

Now, change your script in order to use this template file when connecting to a Server:

```
mstsc "C:\temp\MyRDPtemplate.rdp" /v:$Server
```

When you first connect to a Server while mapping local resources, you will receive a warning message:

[image: Warning local resources mapped]

If you want to avoid this message, add the following registry key before launching:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\LocalDevices" /v $Server /t "REG_DWORD" /d 0x4d /f
mstsc "C:\temp\MyRDPtemplate.rdp" /v:$Server
```

There may be a global parameter you can add to avoid this message for all Servers (like for "AuthenticationLevelOverride") but I don't know for sure.

On last word about the stored credentials... if you use cmdkey /generic:xxx, you don't need to specify the service type (TERMSRV), that's the purpose of the /generic switch. But it also works fine...

**PS:** Very last remark, if you want to bypass the certificate prompt (in case your server doesn't present a valid one, you should add the registry key **AuthenticationLevelOverride** before connecting to the Server. Also note that this key is valid for all connections.

Answer (score 0):

Another choice is get a help form some 3rd-part tools for RDP.

https://github.com/VShawn/PRemoteM